# Обтекание блока или как сделать контент по центру

Tags: html, css, float, display

> Вопрос закрыт. Решение: на разных медиазапросах изменить `max-width` контейнера по ширине блоков (3-х, 2-х, а потом 1-го).

Доброго времени суток!
Есть проблема с версткой.. Не могу никак выровнять контент по центру:

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/t4Lxs220/4/)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrappper {
  max-width: 1260px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 0;
}

.image {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 415px;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  background: #ccc;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}

.inf {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 415px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}

.inf {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrappper">
  <div class="image">1</div>
  <div class="inf">Підбір персоналу</div>
  <div class="inf">Вакансія PROMO</div>
  <div class="inf">Мотивація персоналу</div>
  <div class="inf">Оцінка персоналу</div>
</div>
```

Работает только вначале, но когда элементы складываются, отцентровка не работает. Я понимаю из-за чего, но как это обойти? Есть хаки возможно? Кто-то стыкался с таким?

[image: Отцентровка при ширине контейнера в 1200+ px]
[image: Когда элементы сужаються]

Comment: примера нет...  Ты забыл ссылку добавить

Comment: @Air не могу добавить, stack выпендривается.. http://jsfiddle.net/t4Lxs220/4/ вот.

Comment: Объясни толком, они все по центру должны выровняться или как?

Comment: @Air Да. То есть .wrapper должен центрировать их (все блоки: в ряд, или в колонке 2-е, или в столбик все) То есть, ширина контейнера max-width: 1260px должна центрировать элементы по центру (но это не делаеться, когда переносятся блоки)

Comment: @Air Кстати, если прописать .wrapper `display:table; text-align:center;`, посмотри результат, почти то, что надо! Только теперь `float: left` мешает центровке...

Comment: Посмотри ответ, я тя правильно понял?

Comment: Если у вас ширина блока будет фиксированой, почему бы через несколько медиа запросов не изменить ширину wrapper?

Comment: @E_K Да, такое решение приносят свои плоды, спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

А теперь слушай. Я у тебя убрал `line-height: 200px;`, так как это не лучшее решение, чтобы у блока с такой высотой выравнивать текст по центру по `ось-Y`, 
лучше засунуть их в `<span>` и уже его выровнять по `ось-Y`...  Еще проблема в том, что у тебя ширина и высота внутренних блоков фиксированная, и выравнивать их по `ось-Х` в ряд я не вижу смысла. Я конечно не в праве указывать тебе как и что ты должен делать, но это я к тому, что не могу понять что именно ты хочешь реализовать

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrappper {
  max-width: 1260px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  background: red;
}

.leftWrap {
  flex-grow: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.rigthWrap {
  flex-grow: 2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 415px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #ccc;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.inf {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 415px;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 25px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrappper">
  <div class="leftWrap">
    <div class="image"><span>1</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="rigthWrap">
    <div class="inf"><span>Підбір персоналу</span></div>
    <div class="inf"><span>Вакансія PROMO</span></div>
    <div class="inf"><span>Мотивація персоналу</span></div>
    <div class="inf"><span>Оцінка персоналу</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Нет, колонки должны ОБТЕКАТЬ блок под низом, когда ширина меньше (то есть 2 последних блока (в высоту) не влазят и они автоматом под низ попадают под блок ГЛАВНЫЙ (серый как у тебя) и под блоки `<div class="inf">Підбір персоналу</div>  <div class="inf">Вакансія PROMO</div>`

Comment: я пример показал же, оно работает, только центровки нету

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, нужно центрировать только 1-й блок.

```
.image {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrappper {
  max-width: 1260px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 0;
}

.image {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 415px;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  background: #ccc;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}

.inf {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 415px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}

.inf {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrappper">
  <div class="image">1</div>
  <div class="inf">Підбір персоналу</div>
  <div class="inf">Вакансія PROMO</div>
  <div class="inf">Мотивація персоналу</div>
  <div class="inf">Оцінка персоналу</div>
</div>
```

Comment: результат  тот же, что и на примере :)  
Я решил даный вопрос при помощи bootstrap, но верстка все равно не дает желаемого результата